# JWT Auth with Laravel Blade

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, jwt, laravel-blade

I'm going to build a website with Laravel 5.3. I want to use JWT auth but I don't find any tutorials to use it with laravel blade.

So, I'm asking if there is a way to use JWT with laravel blades..  or should I use the laravel auth system ??

Comment: try https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport instead of JWT

Comment: There is a useful answer here by mina: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/jwt-authorization-header-in-web